# Откуда берётся лишняя цифра?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, ideone

Следующий код в VS2015 выводит `x`, но в ideone результат почему-то `x1`. Почему??

http://ideone.com/K5ZKxR

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s = "x";

  s = regex_replace(s + "0123456789", regex("(\\b(?=9.*(1))|0(?=.*(1))|1(?=.*(2))|2(?=.*(3))|3(?=.*(4))|4(?=.*(5))|5(?=.*(6))|6(?=.*(7))|7(?=.*(8))|8(?=.*(9))|9(?=.*(0)))(?=9*-)|\\d{10}$"), "$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12");
  cout << s << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

В приведённом примере совпадение должно идти *только* по последней ветви `|\\d{10}$`, т. е. все группы должны быть пустыми. Т. о. должен удалиться добавленный хвост из 10 цифр. Но откуда-то берётся цифра `1`. Из-за чего так происходит? И как исправить?

---

Уменьшил пример
http://ideone.com/THHiay

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s = "x";

  s = regex_replace(s + "0123456789", regex("0(?=.*(1))(?=9*-)|\\d{10}$"), "<$1>");
  cout << s << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

```
x<1>
```

При этом другие нули в строке не портятся (меняются только перед девятками и дефисом)
http://ideone.com/XcFF6M

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s = "100#100-100,101#101-101,109#109-109";

  s = regex_replace(s + "0123456789", regex("0(?=.*(1))(?=9*-)|\\d{10}$"), "<$1>");
  cout << s << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

```
100#10<1>-100,101#101-101,109#1<1>9-109<1>
```

Тем временем, VS на последний пример выдаёт

```
100#10<1>-100,101#101-101,109#1<1>9-109<>
```

Что логично - группы нет, но замена со стиранием хвоста есть.

Comment: логично, что не сработавшие ветки поиска не сохраняют групп (заменив `?=` на `?:` получим ожидаемый результат), поэтому можно предположить, что это баг компилятора

Comment: @BOPOH, а есть аналоги ideone, поддерживающие 11й или 14й стандарт плюсов?

Comment: Это баг, не должны захватываться в группы несработавшие альтернативы. Конкретно это регулярное выражение можо вылечить так: http://ideone.com/B9n6fo

Comment: @ReinRaus Что, репортим баг на GCC (или что там)? :)

Comment: @Discord, в чате [говорят](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29252824#29252824), на g++ нормально работает. Похоже, у ideone какая-то специфическая версия? Или это вообще какая-то рантайм-библиотека их линуксового дистрибутива?

Comment: @Qwertiy Куда-то этот баг всё равно отрепортить надо... Можно попытаться пнуть IDEOne.

Comment: http://cpp.sh/ - код отрабатывает как ожидается, т.е. все-таки на ideone репорт слать

Comment: Тогда напишите ответ, кто-нибудь.

Comment: @Qwertiy закройте, пожалуйста, вопрос, а то его на протяжении еще пары лет обсуждать будут :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, что-то он полгода неотвеченный провалялся. Зачем его закрывать, если баг как был, так и остался? А вот ответ принял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему это не баг ideone, а баг gcc, появившийся где-то в районе версии 5.

[4.9.3](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rzKh8zT2ExeDZC6a) дает:

> x<>

[5.1.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gV2u3SSBxmSCViIV) дает:

> x<1>

Answer (score 2):

Как верно указал @ReinRaus, это действительно баг Ideone.

Я написал в их службу поддержки по этому поводу.